# External ADC and FIFO

Tags: sampling, signal

I have a Micro-controller with ADC input range 0V to 3.6V(12 bit). I need to measure a voltage signal in the range of -10V to +10V. So i chose the option of using an external ADC instead of the internal one. Now the problem is, i need an ADC which has a high sampling rate, say 1MHz.Even though i found many bipolar ADCs with high sampling rate, i came to know that without an internal buffer for storing the converted data we cant achieve the specified data transfer speed i.e effectively 1MHz cant be achieved.

So then i searched for adc with internal fifo.But for adcs with fifo, sampling rate specified is very less.What to do? Kindly help me.(adc should have spi feature too).

Comment: Why are you finding that data transfer limits your sample rate? Many modern microcontrollers are able to handle that.

Comment: *What* microcontroller specifically?

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution that I usually employ is just to modify the signal level using an analog amplifier, in that way you will be able to use the internal adc. A very simple operational amplifier circuit can convert from -10:+10 to 0:3.6 a very common configuration is shown here: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_5.html

I believe this is cheaper and simpler than using an external adc.